# ListView in Android PopupWindow

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, baseadapter

Is there a simple example or tutorial, how to put a `ListView` (getting the value from `BaseAdapter` through XML parser) in `PopupWindow` in Android?

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html)

This is how I did it:

`PopupWrapper` class just wraps `PopupWindow` inside a more friendly class:

```
package com.blablabla.android.helpers.gui.dialog;

import com.blablabla.android.helpers.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

/**
 * This class does most of the work of wrapping the {@link PopupWindow} so it's
 * simpler to use.
 */
public class PopupWrapper implements OnTouchListener {

    /** Context where to show the popup */
    protected Context context = null;

    /** The popup to show */
    protected PopupWindow window = null;

    /** What to show in the popup */
    protected View root = null;

    /** Parent/anchor View */
    protected View anchor = null;

    /** Optional background */
    protected Drawable background = null;

    /** Window manager */
    private WindowManager windowManager;

    public PopupWrapper(Activity activity) {        
        anchor = null;
        context = activity; 
        init();
    }

    public PopupWrapper(View anchor) {

        this.anchor = anchor;
        context = anchor.getContext();
        init();     
    }

    private void init() {

        window = new PopupWindow(context);
        window.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        window.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        window.setTouchable(true);
        //window.setFocusable(true);
        window.setOutsideTouchable(true);

        // when a touch even happens outside of the window
        // make the window go away
        window.setTouchInterceptor(this);
        windowManager = (WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        onCreate();
    }

    /**
     * Anything you want to have happen when created. Probably should create a
     * view and setup the event listeners on child views.
     */
    protected void onCreate() {
    }

    /**
     * In case there is stuff to do right before displaying.
     */
    protected void onShow() {
    }

    private void preShow() {
        if (root == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "setContentView was not called with a view to display.");
        }
        onShow();

        if (background == null) {
            window.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        } else {
            window.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
        }

        // if using PopupWindow#setBackgroundDrawable this is the only values of
        // the width and hight that make it work
        // otherwise you need to set the background of the root viewgroup
        // and set the popupwindow background to an empty BitmapDrawable
        window.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        window.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        window.setTouchable(true);
        window.setFocusable(true);
        window.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        window.setContentView(root);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
            window.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background) {
        this.background = background;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the content view. Probably should be called from {@link onCreate}
     * 
     * @param root
     *            the view the popup will display
     */
    public void setContentView(View root) {
        this.root = root;
        window.setContentView(root);
    }

    /**
     * Will inflate and set the view from a resource id
     * 
     * @param layoutResID
     */
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        setContentView(inflator.inflate(layoutResID, null));
    }

    /**
     * If you want to do anything when {@link dismiss} is called
     * 
     * @param listener
     */
    public void setOnDismissListener(PopupWindow.OnDismissListener listener) {
        window.setOnDismissListener(listener);
    }

    /**
     * Displays like a popdown menu from the anchor view
     */
    public void showLikePopDownMenu() {
        showLikePopDownMenu(0, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Displays like a popdown menu from the anchor view.
     * 
     * @param xOffset
     *            offset in X direction
     * @param yOffset
     *            offset in Y direction
     */
    public void showLikePopDownMenu(int xOffset, int yOffset) {
        preShow();

        window.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animations_PopDownMenu);

        window.showAsDropDown(anchor, xOffset, yOffset);
    }

    /**
     * Displays like a QuickAction from the anchor view.
     */
    public void showLikeQuickAction() {
        showLikeQuickAction(0, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Displays like a QuickAction from the anchor view.
     * 
     * @param xOffset
     *            offset in the X direction
     * @param yOffset
     *            offset in the Y direction
     */
    public void showLikeQuickAction(int xOffset, int yOffset) {
        preShow();

        window.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animations_GrowFromBottom);

        int[] location = new int[2];
        anchor.getLocationOnScreen(location);

        Rect anchorRect = new Rect(location[0], location[1], location[0]
                + anchor.getWidth(), location[1] + anchor.getHeight());

        root.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        int rootWidth = root.getMeasuredWidth();
        int rootHeight = root.getMeasuredHeight();

        int screenWidth = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        //int screenHeight = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        int xPos = ((screenWidth - rootWidth) / 2) + xOffset;
        int yPos = anchorRect.top - rootHeight + yOffset;

        // display on bottom
        if (rootHeight > anchorRect.top) {
            yPos = anchorRect.bottom + yOffset;
            window.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animations_GrowFromTop);
        }

        window.showAtLocation(anchor, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, xPos, yPos);
    }

    public void dismiss() {
        window.dismiss();
    }

    public void showAtLocation(int gravity, int x, int y) {
        window.showAtLocation(anchor, gravity, x, y);
    }
}
```

`FileExplorer` class is an example of using `PopupWrapper`:

```
package com.blablabla.android.helpers.gui.dialog.fexplorer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.blablabla.android.helpers.R;
import com.blablabla.android.helpers.gui.ViewHelper;
import com.blablabla.android.helpers.gui.dialog.PopupWrapper;
import com.blablabla.android.helpers.util.FileHelper;
import com.blablabla.android.helpers.util.Log;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Simple file explorer popup window. Only allows selecting one normal file (no
 * directory).
 * 
 * @author mymail@blablabla.eu
 * 
 */
public class FileExplorer extends PopupWrapper implements Runnable,
        OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = FileExplorer.class.getName();

    /** ListView for the file listing */
    private ListView fileList = null;

    /** Top path (cannot go backward than this) */
    private File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getPath());

    /** Current path */
    private File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getPath());

    /** Selected item */
    private File selected = null;

    /** Who to notify when file selecting finished */
    private OnFileSelectedListener listener = null;

    /** Show hidden files or not */
    private boolean showHidden = false;

    public FileExplorer(Activity activity, boolean showHidden) {
        this(activity);
        this.showHidden = showHidden;
    }

    public FileExplorer(Activity activity) {
        super(activity);

        // View to show on the popup
        root = ViewHelper.inflateViewById(activity, R.layout.explorer);

        // Parent view
        anchor = ViewHelper.getRootView(activity);

        // Listeners
        initializeViews();
    }

    /** Initializes View listeners */
    private void initializeViews() {

        // Set up the popup window
        window.setFocusable(true);
        window.setContentView(root);
        window.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        window.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        window.setClippingEnabled(true);

        // Set up ListView
        fileList = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.explorer_list);
        fileList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        fileList.setSelector(android.R.drawable.screen_background_light_transparent);
        fileList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        // Set up button listeners
        ImageButton dirup = (ImageButton) root.findViewById(R.id.explorer_up);
        dirup.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button but = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.explorer_ok);
        but.setOnClickListener(this);

        but = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.explorer_cancel);
        but.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    /** First time load with files in path */
    private void loadList() {

        File[] finalList;
        try {
            finalList = FileHelper.getFileList(path, showHidden);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), true);
            return;
        }

        FileExplorerAdapter list = (FileExplorerAdapter) fileList.getAdapter();

        // No adapter set yet
        if (list == null) {
            // Java's way of life... most stupid thing ever
            List<File> aux = new ArrayList<File>();
            aux.addAll(Arrays.asList(finalList));
            FileExplorerAdapter adapter = new FileExplorerAdapter(context,
                    aux);
            fileList.setAdapter(adapter);

        } else { // Modify adapter
            list.clear();
            list.addAll(finalList);
            list.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void show() {
        loadList();
        showAtLocation(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        show();
    }

    /** Set path to show */
    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = new File(path);
    }

    /** Show or not hidden files */
    public void showHidden(boolean show) {
        showHidden = show;
    }

    /** Refresh the list with current set path */
    public void refresh() {
        loadList();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {       

        // Cannot use a switch/case...
        int id = v.getId();     
        if (id == R.id.explorer_up) {
            dirUp();            
        } else if (id == R.id.explorer_ok) {
            ok();
        } else if (id == R.id.explorer_cancel) {
            //cancel();
        }

    }

    /** Called when "explorer_up" button is clicked */
    public void dirUp() {
        File newPath = path.getParentFile();
        if (newPath != null) {
            path = newPath;
            loadList();
        }
    }

    /** Called when "explorer_ok" button is clicked */
    public void ok() {
        if (selected == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Nothing selected");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, selected.getPath());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int pos, long id) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick");
        selected = (File) fileList.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    }
}
```

And finally the layout for the popup window:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/explorer_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:text="@string/explorer_title"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/explorer_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" >

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/explorer_up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/dirup_icon"
            android:onClick="dirUp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/explorer_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="@string/ok"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/explorer_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The only problem with this implementation is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706520/problems-with-listview-inside-a-popupwindow)

Answer (score -1):

Try This....

```
public class hotelListAct extends ListActivity {


    TextView hn, ad, pr;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<search_hotel_setterGetter> result;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.combine);

        // this is array of your result which you get while xml parsing.
        result = new search_hotel_xmlhandler().search_hotel;

        lv = getListView();

        MyAdapter madp = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listact,result);
        lv.setAdapter(madp);
        lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {


            }
        });
    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<search_hotel_setterGetter> arrayList;
        Context baseContext;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<search_hotel_setterGetter> array) {
            super();
            arrayList = array;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.baseContext = context;
        }
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arrayList.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arrayList.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listact, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                holder.Hname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                holder.address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
                holder.rating = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
                holder.city = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.lowrate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lowrate);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                 holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            if (arrayList != null) {

                 holder.image.setImageBitmap(arrayList.get(position).getImageUrl());
                 holder.Hname.setText(arrayList.get(position).getname());
                 holder.address.setText(arrayList.get(position).getaddress());
                 holder.rating.setRating(Float.parseFloat(arrayList.get(position).getrating()));
                 holder.city.setText(arrayList.get(position).getcity());
                 holder.lowrate.setText(arrayList.get(position).getLowRate());
            } else {
                Log.d("array", "null");
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder{

        TextView Hname;
        TextView address;
        TextView city;
        ImageView image;
        RatingBar rating;
        TextView lowrate;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @patel but where is the PopupWindow.....!!? my problem is that I have a tabbed Layout, in the middle tab I have button which I should click on it to get the PopupWindow with ListView comes from XML parsing.....!!