# Problems with ListView inside a PopupWindow

Tags: android, listview, popupwindow

I have a `ListView` in a `PopupWindow`. The `PopupWindow` is initialized like this

```
    window.setContentView(root);
    window.setTouchable(true);
    window.setFocusable(true);
    window.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    window.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    window.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Then the `ListView`:

```
    fileList = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.explorer_list);
    fileList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    fileList.setSelector(android.R.drawable.screen_background_light_transparent);
    fileList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    [...]

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int pos, long id) {
        selected = (File) fileList.getItemAtPosition(pos);      
    }
```

Like this, everything works correctly except that the selector will not show up on selection until `ListView` is scrolled (nothing shows visually as selected until the list is scrolled, although the item is correctly selected).

If I set the `PopupWindow` not focusable, then the visual selection works correctly (the item is visually selected right when clicked into) but `onItemClick()` is never called and thus I cannot get the selected item.

`ListView.getSelectedItem()` always returns `null` in both cases, even if there's a selected item.

Any idea on how to solve this situation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally used a custom adapter to store the selected value and use it from there to mark it:

```
public class FileExplorerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<File> {

    /** File names */
    private List<File> values = new ArrayList<File>();

    /** Currently selected position */
    private int selected = -1;

    public FileExplorerAdapter(Context context, List<File> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.explorer_row, values);
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // I know that my layout is always a TextView
        TextView row = (TextView) convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            row = (TextView) ViewHelper.inflateViewById(getContext(),
                    R.layout.explorer_row);
        }

        // More code...

        // Set up the background for selected element
        if (selected == position) {
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

        // Override background selector
        } else {
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

        // More code...

        return row;
    }

    /** This sets the selected position */
    public void setSelected(int position) {
        selected = position;
    }
}
```

And on the class that implements the `OnItemClickListener` for the associated `ListView`, I set up the currently selected item in the adapter.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int pos, long id) {
    FileExplorerAdapter fileadapter = (FileExplorerAdapter) fileList
            .getAdapter();
    fileadapter.setSelected(pos);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//Set listview focusable properties to false

android:focusable="false"

Comment: answered Oct 4 '12 at 9:33... If I set ListView not focusable, I cannot select items my dear.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, but in my case `PopupWindow.setFocusble(false)` was required (and using `ListPopupWindow` was not a solution in my case as a lot of stuff in the project already used base `PopupWindow`'s functionality including extending).

If someone in the same situation there is a kind of workaround based on bug discusson [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414) (post #9)

The main idea is that `ListView`'s hierarchy is still receives touch events so we can manually trigger `onItemClick()`.

However this approach is not 100% identical to real `ListView`'s touch handling (like there is no glow of selection while tapping a row) this done pretty well for me for the moment.

If someone has more precise solution of this problem, please share.

So, here is complete `Adapter`'s code which can be used with `ListView` inside `PopupWindow` which is `setFocusable(false)`:

private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ListView mOwningListView;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> objects, ListView listView) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objects);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mOwningListView = listView;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.font_pick_row, null);
    }
    // this is the key point of workaround
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*
             *  as every row is still receiving their touches
             *  we can use this to manually trigger onItemClick
             *  since it doesn't firing in popupWindow.setFocusable(false)  
             */
            mOwningListView.getOnItemClickListener().onItemClick(mOwningListView, v, position, getItemId(position));

        }
    });
    //... other stuff
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
fileList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long arg3) {
            selected = (File) fileList.getItemAtPosition(pos);    

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    } );
```

Comment: Thank you but I already tried this. `OnItemSelectedListener` has the same problem than `OnItemClickedListener`: it is never called when `PopupWindow` is not focusable.

Comment: Well in fact `OnItemSelectedListener` is never called, no matter what.