# Creating Options / Spinner Menus

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu that doesn't swap text like a traditional spinner. Ideally, I'd like to have an icon that triggers the dropdown seen below when tapped.

Is there a better way to create dropdowns like this?

**EDIT: Android Popup Menu is the way to go!**

The example below was created with a dropdown spinner.

**What I Have:**

[image: dropdownexample]

**What I Want:**

[image: dropdownexample2]

**Spinner Code:**

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.addCustomer);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
getActivity(), R.array.add_customer, R.layout.spinner_item_icon);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item_icon);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having a `PopupWindow`. When you click the icon, you can show a `PopupWindow` with `ListView`. You can find sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897561/android-listview-in-android-popupwindow)

Comment: Just found that haha :) Thanks.